# Solving $(\cos{(x)} - I_1)^2 + (\cos{(x - \rho_2)} - I_2)^2 + (\cos{(x - \rho_3)} - I_3)^2 = 0$ analytically?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-optimization

As part of an algorithm, I have to solve the following equation, with constants $I_1,I_2, I_3, \rho_2, \rho_3$ and variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$(\cos{(x)} - I_1)^2 + (\cos{(x - \rho_2)} - I_2)^2 + (\cos{(x - \rho_3)} - I_3)^2 = 0$$

I solved it successfully with numerically approaches. However, does exist any analytical solution? I ask out of interest and understanding.

If there isn't any analytical solution, would it rather a good idea to use a root-finding algorithm or minimization approach, with 0 as minimum. I have used the second method right now (with pythons library scipy), but I'm still interested if there are any better approach.

Comment: If a sum of (real) squares equals zero, then each square (and, thus, each expression being squared) individually must be zero.

Comment: Oh cool, that makes sense, thanks. But since $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I couldn't solve the single equations with arctan, could I?

Comment: If the eqn has an *actual* soln, then you can simply solve $\cos x=I_1$ (getting principal value $x=\arccos I_1$); the other constants would need to be compatible w/this soln so that $\cos(x-\rho_2)=I_2$ and $\cos(x-\rho_3)=I_3$. If the constants are independent, then there won't generally be a soln for $x$, only a value that minimizes the left-hand side. To find it, you can do the standard thing of setting the derivative equal to zero; this ultimately yields a quartic eqn best solved numerically. The Python library may be handling that for you well enough. (I don't use the language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you need to solve for $x$ the three equations
$$\cos{(x)} - I_1=0$$
$$\cos{(x - \rho_2)} - I_2=0$$
$$\cos{(x - \rho_3)} - I_3=0$$

If the solution exist, the  problem is more than simple. But, as @Blue commented, what would happen if the sum of the three ssquares is not strictly equal to $0$ ?

To face such a case, consider minimizing
$$\Phi(x)=w_1\big [\cos{(x)} - I_1\big ]^2 +w_2 \big [\cos{(x - \rho_2)} - I_2\big ]^2 + w_3 \big [\cos{(x - \rho_3)} - I_3\big ]^2 $$

Differentiate $\Phi(x)$ and use the tangent half-angle substitution $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ to face a quartic equation in $t$

$$a_0+a_1\,t+a_2\,t^2+a_3\,t^3+a_4\,t^4=0$$ where

$${a_0}= w_2 \sin (\rho _2) (\cos (\rho _2)-I_2)+ w_3 \sin (\rho _3) (\cos (\rho_3)-I_3)$$
$$\frac{a_1}2=I_2 w_2 \cos (\rho _2)+I_3 w_3 \cos (\rho _3)+(I_1-1) w_1-w_2 \cos (2 \rho_2)-w_3 \cos (2 \rho _3)$$
$$\frac{a_2}3=-w_2 \sin (2 \rho _2)-w_3 \sin (2 \rho_3)$$
$$\frac{a_3}2=w_2 (I_2 \cos (\rho_2)+\cos (2 \rho _2))+w_3 (I_3 \cos (\rho _3)+\cos (2\rho _3))+w_1(I_1+1) $$
$${a_4}=w_2 \sin (\rho _2) (I_2+\cos (\rho _2))+w_3 \sin (\rho _3) (I_3+\cos (\rho_3))$$ and you can start Newton iterations quite safely since each equation gives an intial value; these could be averaged and weighted.

This is a kind of data reconciliation or validation : find the most probable value of $x$ such that $\cdots\cdots$.

**Example**

Consider the following case
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 i &w_i & \rho_i & I_i & x_i \\
 1 & 1 &  & 0.80 & 0.64350\\
 2 & 1 & \frac{\pi }{8} & 0.95 & 0.71026\\
 3 & 1 & \frac{\pi }{6} & 1.00 & 0.52360
\end{array}
\right)$$

The $x_i$ being the individual solution, using their mean $x_0=0.62579$ gives $t_0=0.32352$.

Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 0.3235206909 \\
 1 & 0.3396461907 \\
 2 & 0.3381779968 \\
 3 & 0.3381648286 \\
 4 & 0.3381648276
\end{array}
\right)$$

which gives $x=0.6521851567$